# Nginx ignores return directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

**The problem:**

I have an application running with Nginx serving as a reverse proxy. I have a ssl certificate to a certain `example.com`, but I also want my application to respond to `example.organization.com` (even without a certificate for the domain).

My idea was to set a return directive to return the desired URL and `301` as the status code... The problem is, my directive is not being used by Nginx. The nginx does force a HTTPS connection, but with any URL used and returning `302`, so with the `example.organization.com` the browser does not accept it because of the lack of a ssl certificate. Even when the `listen 80` block is disabled the redirect still goes on. Nginx is running inside a Docker container and it's hitting another Docker container (I don't think it is influencing the behavior, but I'm not sure)

**What I've tried:**

I tried to use the `rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri permanent` instead of the `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri`.

I also tried this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    if ($host != "example.com") {
        return 301 https://example.com;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.

**server configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com example.organization.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf/cert.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container:80/
    }

    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```